# How to create polynomials from strings

Tags: sage

I would like to create Boolean polynomials from strings. At the moment I define polynomials by using implicitly defined variables:

```
R = BooleanPolynomialRing(names=["a", "b", "c"], order=TermOrder("lex"))
R.inject_variables()

f = 1 + a*b
g = a*b*(1+c)
```

I would like to define `f` and `g` in terms of strings `"1 + a*b"` and `"a*b*(1+c)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial ring can take strings and transform them into polynomials.

```py
sage: R = BooleanPolynomialRing(names=["a", "b", "c"], order=TermOrder("lex"))
sage: R.inject_variables()
Defining a, b, c

sage: f = R("1 + a*b")
sage: f
a*b + 1

sage: g = R("a*b*(1+c)")
sage: g
a*b*c + a*b
```